# DoubleAnimation for image with Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have read [How can I make an Image grow in size (give the illusion of selection) through a WPF animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936353/how-can-i-make-an-image-grow-in-size-give-the-illusion-of-selection-through-a) and tried to change the height of an image with a `DoubleAnimation` but it does not work.

```
<Image Name="image" Height="100" Source="http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png" Stretch="None">
        <Image.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="show">
                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="image"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                     From="100" To="400" Duration="0:0:1"
                    />
            </Storyboard>
        </Image.Resources>
    </Image>
    <Button Content="image stretch" Click="button_clicked" />
```

This is the `button_clicked` function:

```cs
private void button_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    show.Begin();
}
```

[edit]: Because Johan Falk´s answer I tried the above code with the Windows Phone Silverlight toolkit and it works. So the solution is to use Windows Phone Silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a small error in your code, by setting `Stretch="None"` you don't allow the image to stretch in any direction, hence Always keeping its original size. Change `Stretch` to for example `Uniform` and it should work.

Here is the sample code I used to verify it with:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Image Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" x:Name="testImage" Stretch="Uniform">
        <Image.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="Animation">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="testImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="100" To="200" Duration="0:0:1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Image.Resources>
    </Image>
    <Button Content="Expand image" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Animation.Begin();
}
```

Comment: I want to use Stretch="None" so not the whole image is visible. Tried your solution it does not work even when I set Stretch="uniform". Did you use the Windows Phone Toolkit or the Windows Phone Silverlight?

Comment: I used Windows Phone Silverlight. If you want to just "hide" part of the image, not stretch it when you change the height, put the image inside a StackPanel for example and animate the height of the StackPanel instead